# MYSQL Query WITH a subQ

Tags: mysql

I am trying to grab all of the SUMS for columns, as I am doing this I want to JOIN the shipped filed so I am only grabbing SUMS of current orders that have not shipped. From my efforts I keep getting a result in which all the columns are wrong amounts calculated. THANK YOU IN ADVANCE.

I believe I need to write a subQ, but I am having issues trying to get there.
If I remove the JOIN, the result is perfect, no problems, but I need the join so I am only calculating non shipped items. I believe its pulling some other records from the join table. THANK YOU IN ADVANCE.

```
SELECT XX.order_num, XX.shipped, PP.order_num AS JON, PP.part_num AS JPT, SUM(PP.total_qty) AS QTY, SUM(PP.work_time) AS WT,SUM(PP.setup_time) AS ST,SUM(PP.scrap) AS SC 
  FROM PP
    JOIN XX 
    ON XX.order_num = PP.order_num
  WHERE PP.department='RIBBON' 
  AND PP.ribbon_type='CRIMPING' AND XX.shipped IS NULL
  GROUP BY part_num 
  ORDER BY PP.order_num DESC
```

I am getting this:

```
so185702    6609628 8,120   92.67 HRS   1.92 HRS    0
```

When it should read this:

```
so185702        6609628   760      545            15            0
```

I just need help in writing the subQ, I am still a beginner. THANK YOU.

Answer (score 0):

When you mix normal columns with aggregate functions (like sum), you need the `GROUP BY`-clause where you list all columns in `SELECT` which do not have the aggregate function. In your query the first four columns:

```
SELECT 
  XX.order_num, 
  XX.shipped, 
  PP.order_num AS JON, 
  PP.part_num AS JPT, 
  SUM(PP.total_qty) AS QTY, 
  SUM(PP.work_time) AS WT,
  SUM(PP.setup_time) AS ST,
  SUM(PP.scrap) AS SC 
FROM PP
  JOIN XX ON XX.order_num = PP.order_num
WHERE PP.department='RIBBON' AND PP.ribbon_type='CRIMPING' AND XX.shipped IS NULL
GROUP BY XX.order_num, XX.shipped, PP.order_num, PP.part_num 
ORDER BY PP.order_num DESC
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help, but unfortunately I received the same result with this statement. It was multiplying the SUMS.

Comment: In that case you have multiple XX's matching individual PP's. What you should show is sample data with expected result.

Comment: WORKING MYSQL WITHOUT "JOIN"
SELECT job_time.order_num AS JON, job_time.part_num AS JPT, SUM(job_time.total_qty) AS QTY, SUM(job_time.work_time) AS WT,SUM(job_time.setup_time) AS ST,SUM(job_time.scrap) AS SC from job_time 
WHERE job_time.department='RIBBON' AND job_time.ribbon_type='CRIMPING' 
GROUP BY part_num ORDER BY job_time.order_num DESC

Comment: RESULT without JOIN  -------

so186405 6609280 350 290 0 0
so186182 6609627 300 240 5 0
so186182 6609750 150 140 10 0
so186181 6609980 100 70 4 0
so185702 6609628 840 613 20 0
so185702 6610505 400 230 10 0
so185702 6609620 350 310 10 0
SO185702 6609670 158 130 7 0
so185701 6617570 350 320 20 0
so185701 6617008 350 945 42 0
so185701 6617340 650 525 10 0
so185701 6617567 349 345 5 0
so185698 6617568 663 997 38 0
so185698 6617775 202 150 10 0
so185698 6617843 462 595 21 0

Comment: MYSQL WITH "JOIN":

SELECT prod_admin.order_num,job_time.order_num AS JON, job_time.part_num AS JPT, SUM(job_time.total_qty) AS QTY, SUM(job_time.work_time) AS WT,SUM(job_time.setup_time) AS ST,SUM(job_time.scrap) AS SC from job_time 
JOIN prod_admin ON prod_admin.order_num=job_time.order_num
WHERE job_time.department='RIBBON' AND job_time.ribbon_type='CRIMPING' AND prod_admin.shipped IS NULL
GROUP BY part_num ORDER BY job_time.order_num DESC

Comment: RESULT with JOIN INCORRECT---
SO186405 NULL so186405 6609280 350 290 0 0
SO186182 NULL so186182 6609627 2100 1680 35 0
SO186182 NULL so186182 6609750 1050 980 70 0
SO186181 NULL so186181 6609980 800 560 32 0
SO185702 NULL so185702 6609628 8760 6104 155 0
SO185702 NULL so185702 6610505 8800 5060 220 0
SO185702 NULL so185702 6609620 7700 6820 220 0
SO185702 NULL SO185702 6609670 3476 2860 154 0
SO185701 NULL so185701 6617008 3600 8895 438 0
SO185701 NULL so185701 6617340 7050 5835 90 0
SO185701 NULL so185701 6617570 4200 3840 240 0
SO185701 NULL so185701 6617567 4188 4140 60 0